# enumeration, full stop and \ref-\label formulations

Tags: lists, enumitem

I have a question regarding enumeration.

I am busy setting exams in LaTeX and using the enumitem package. I would like the questions be numbered as follows with a fullstop after the number (because students hyped up on caffeine and inebriated by sleep deprivation are easily confused):

```
1.
2.
3...
```

But I would also like the call the questions using the form `Q\ref{label1}`. So I label the questions where needed:

```
1. blah de blah blah blah \label{label1}
2. blah blah blah \label{label2}
3. Charlie Brown's dad says "blur blah blur blue." \label{label3}
```

When I call the questions in the form `Q\ref{label1}--\label{label3}` I get "Q1.--3." which is especially ugly if the sequence terminates the sentence.

Is there a way that I can set the number scheme to add the "." in the list but not in the called question so I still have

```
1.
2.
3.
```

but can get "Q1--3" instead?

Comment: Please always provide a complete minimal example people can copy-paste and compile to reproduce the problem. Mere code fragments are almost always of very limited use. (Even if your fragments turn out to be sufficient here, which they may not.) You will also get more helpful answers back. Fragmentary and information-impoverished questions tend to elicit similar answers.

Comment: The setting you say you want -- dots after the labels in the enumerated list but not after cross-references to list items -- *is the default setting*, with or without the `enumitem` package. If this isn't the case in your document, something else must be going on that has modified the defaults.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*]
...
```

Or add it to the definition of your custom list or whatever.